# Logarithm multiplication property error, can't figure out why.

Tags: logarithms

I know there is a mistake and where it is but I can't figure out why.

Equation:
$$
3+2(12^{x+1}) = 291
$$

From here I do:
$$
2(12^{x+1}) = 291-3\\
2(12^{x+1}) = 288\\
$$

Then I take the natural logarithms on both sides;
$$
\ln(2*12^{x+1}) = \ln(288)\\
\ln(2*12^{x+1}) = \ln(2*12^2)\\
$$

Now I apply multiplication property so $\ln(a*b)$ should equal $\ln(a)+\ln(b)$
But here it seems that I'm making a mistake, can't figure out why:

$$
\ln(2) + \ln(12^{x+1}) = \ln(2) + \ln(12^2)\\
$$

subtract $\ln(2)$ on both sides:
$$
\ln(12^{x+1}) = \ln(12^2) \\
$$

Then it should be:
$$
(x+1) \ln(12) = 2 \ln(12)\\
x+1 = 2\\
x=1\\
$$

but it's not the right result..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is the right result: you can check it at once substituting in the original question. Why do you way it isn't?

Comment: it is the correct answer like Timbuc said

Comment: check your question again since the answer you got is 100% right according to your posted question

Comment: sorry I was confused by a step by step solver website, I should have checked the equation by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation
\begin{align}
3 + 2 \cdot 12^{x+1} = 291
\end{align}
leads to
\begin{align}
2 \cdot 12^{x+1} &= 291-3 = 288 \\
12^{x+1} &= 144 = 12^{2}
\end{align}
for which $x+1 = 2$ by equating the exponents, or taking the logarithm of both sides. The value of $x$ is $x=1$.